# MongoDB sort top n entries

Tags: mongodb

I would like to be able to grab the ten most recent entries in the database and sort them by price with the most expensive first. (Date and price are just examples; this could apply to any two sortable fields.) If I sort by price, I won't get the ten most recent entries, so I have to sort by time. When I sort by time, though, the results are ordered by time instead of price. Can I make a query that grabs the documents by time and orders them by price? Or do I have to sort the entries after the query has returned them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your document has a structure similar to:

```
 {_id: ObjectId("50a8240b927d5d8b5891743c"),
 price: 12,
 date: new Date("Oct 04, 2012")}
```

From the console you could run the following query:

```
db.prices.find({'date':ISODate("Oct 04, 2012")}).sort({'price':-1});
```

This will find all objects that have the date set to **Oct 04, 2014** and orders them **descending** based on price.

If you want to reverse the sorting order you can replace the sorting query with: **'price':1**

**EDIT:**

Also if you want to have multiple sorting fields, like getting the most recent in time with the highest price you could use the query bellow:

```
db.prices.find().sort({'price':-1,'date':-1})
```

**EDIT 2:**

As with the updated comment the query should get the top ten newest items and sort them by price having the most expensive first:

```
db.prices.find().sort({'date':-1}).limit(10).sort({'p':-1});
```

This is the only way i can think of at the moment.
Get the first 10 items sorted by date and after that apply another filter to sort them by price.

Comment: I can't tell if you haven't fully understood the question or if you're suggesting an alternative because what I've described isn't possible. Please let me know if there's anything I can clarify.

Comment: You want to sort by two fields and make sure that they are sorted in the exact order as the sorting fields: meaning that you first sort them by price and make sure that the first has the highest price and it is the nearest in time?

Comment: I want to show only the ten newest items regardless of price, but I want to display them in order of price instead of in order of time.

Comment: Updated my answer hope it helps.

Comment: That's great. I want the ten newest, not the ten most expensive, though, so I'll just swap price and date in the query.